# how to use $q.all(promises) and display the responses on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am new to Angularjs. I wanna send two GET queries to get responses from two urls, but I can only get responses from the first url (which is shown in the screenshot of console) and cannot display it on the webpage.

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks a lot.

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWTCO.png)

[screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49HIv.png)

Comment: No one can help you without going through your code...

Comment: You should add the code to your question rather than just posting screenshots.

Comment: Do pass `array` as argument for `$q.all`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push($http.get("url1"));
promises.push($http.get("url2"));

$q.all(promises).then(function (data){
    $scope.course = data[0];
    $scope.location = data[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your urls in an array in `$q.all` like

```
$q.all([$http.get("url1"),$http.get("url2")]).then(function (data){
  console.log(data[0]);   //response from 1st url
  console.log(data[1]);   // response from 2nd url
});
```